# dependencies not being downloaded from Jfrog artifactory using gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, artifactory

I have my project jar published in Jfrog artifactory after being build. Now when some other project wants to download this and its dependencies, they have added it as a dependency in their build.gradle file. However, when we are trying to execute "gradle dependencies", only the project jar is being downloaded and not its dependencies.
Can someone help why the dependencies are not being downloaded.

Note: The pom.xml for the project jar is not uploaded to artifactory. Is this absolutely mandatory for downloading dependencies for project jar ?

Comment: Uploading the pom.xml is mandatory. How did you upload your jar?

Comment: We are using below in build.gradle for publishing                                              
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = "${repoKey}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_key}"
            maven = true 
        }        
        defaults{
         publications('mavenJava')
         publishArtifacts=true
         publishPom=true
         publications('mavenZip')
         publishPom=true
        }
    }
}